# Как форму созданную в Qt Designer начинить логикой действий? [2]

Tags: python, qt

Всем доброго дня суток, подскажите как прописать логику

```
import sys
from typing import Union, Optional
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QLabel, QPushButton
from design import Ui_main_w
import sys

 class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_main_w):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # ?
        self.btn_summer.clicked.connect(self.func_summer)

def func_summer(self):
    try:

        a_summer_1 = input(float(self.le_summer.text()))
        # ?
        result = round(0.3 * float(a_summer_1) / 100 * 11.5, 2)
        self.out_summer.setText(f'{result}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Рассчитать" была исполнена формула

```
0.3 * float(a_summer_1) / 100 * 11.5, 2
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Замените `a_summer_1 = input(float(self.le_summer.text()))` на `a_summer_1 = float(self.le_summer.text())` и забудьте про `input()`